# Taylor Series as a linear operator $T:C^{k} (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R}) \to C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, taylor-expansion

Can the Taylor series be thought of as either a linear operator $T: C^{k} (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R}) \to C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R})$  given by
$$
Tf=\sum^{k}_{n=0} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n} 
$$
for $f \in C^{k} (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R})$ with the special case  $T:C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R}) \to C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R})$ given by 
$$
Tf =\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}$$
for a function $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R})$? The idea just popped into my head and I wanted to make sure I wasn't going down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Well, you can consider it as an operator for sure, but the question is: Is this an interesting operator. Are these the 'right' spaces to consider? What's the norm of this operator? What's it's spectrum? Obviously, all polynomials (of degree at most $k$) are eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Your second case is not well-defined: not all Taylor series converge. If you replace by $C^\omega $ then you just ha e the identity operator.

Comment: Ian, I was thinking about convergence as well for smooth non-analytic functions (i.e. smooth compactly supported functions) but then I thought that convergence might not matter since I am not suggesting that the original function equals the transformation, merely that the operator produces a function (new or otherwise). Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Also, can someone explain to me the $C^{k}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ notation. I've never seen that before as I'm pretty new to the functional analysis area.

Comment: $C^k(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R}) $ would be all functions $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ which are at least $k$-times differentiable.

Comment: @Neal O ok, I have been writing it as just $C^{k}$, is it more of a matter of preference or taste or is one generally considered better than the other?

Comment: It removes ambiguity. You may want to consider $k$-times continuously differentiable functions from $[0,1]$ to $[-25, \infty)$, for instance: good to have a notation for that. (Also, @Neal the notation means *continuously* differentiable at least $k$ times.)

Comment: @ClementC. The only functions are the continuous functions! ;) But seriously, thank you, if I could edit your correction into my comment I would.

Comment: @Neal No worries (easy to forget a word).

Comment: @AnalysisStudent It can easily happen that the series does not converge to anything. Even when it does there is a concern about the domain; for example, $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ with $a=0$ will get mapped to the restriction of itself to $(-1,1)$.

Comment: The OP's formula would look a LOT nicer in exponential form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for finite $k$ (and a fixed point $a$).  But for $k=\infty$, it doesn't work because the sum $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}$ may not converge.  For instance, if $(c_n)$ is any sequence of real numbers, then there exists a $C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{(n)}(0)=c_n$ for each $n$.  If you choose the $c_n$ to grow fast enough (e.g., $c_n=(n!)^2$), then $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{c_n}{n!}x^{n}$ will not converge for any $x\neq0$.

Comment: Do you mean it wouldn't converge for a function that is both smooth and compactly supported (and thus can't be analytic)? I considered that but for it to be a linear operator, my reasoning is that it wouldn't have to converge, just take a smooth function to a smooth function. Now if I wrote $Tf=f$, then convergence would be an issue? Now I'm pretty new to this so I could be completely wrong and like one of the commenters said, it might not be an interesting operator, but it would it not still be an operator?

Comment: As you say, all you need is for $Tf$ to be a smooth function.  But if the series doesn't converge (not just doesn't converge to $f$, but doesn't converge to _anything_), then $Tf$ isn't even a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ at all!

Comment: O ok now I completely understand what you are saying. So could I then restrict my operator to the set of all taylor series which converge to a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (I assume that if it does converge, it will be smooth)?

Comment: If you restrict $T$ to the set of all smooth functions whose Taylor series around $a$ have infinite radius of convergence then yes, this is a well-defined linear map to $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: To take a specific example illustrating the point: $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $C^\infty$, yet its Taylor series only is defined on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @Eric Ok thank you so much for clearing that up

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you for the counter example

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use this answer to address the concern that AnalysisStudent expressed about "going down the rabbit hole," possibly made precise by Roland in the comments:

> Is this an interesting operator?

Without digging too much into what it means to be an interesting operator, I'll just say that I think the answer is "yes." To motivate that, I'm going to describe a situation where operators similar to this are interesting.

In the numerical approximation of solutions to differential equations, one wishes to obtain methods of producing approximate solutions to differential equations. Such a method often involves parameters, such as geometric approximations, as well as computational limits such as approximating real numbers by floats.

Given such a method, one is concerned with the fundamental questions: As I vary the parameters in the method (for example, make an approximating grid better and better) does the method converge to an actual solution? And, if I have a particular solution arrived at with fixed parameters, how close is it to a the actual solution? These questions are answered with proofs, and underpin confidence in the numerical solutions we arrive at.

Looking at these proofs, I've found it useful to conceptually separate two types of approximations. The first is the approximation of real numbers by floating-point numbers. The second is the approximation of smooth ($C^\infty$) functions by "easily computable" functions. By that, I mean, functions which translate an infinite-dimensional problem, like finding the eigenvalues of a differential operator, into a finite dimensional problem, like finding the eigenvalues of a large matrix.

So the process goes like this:
$$ \mbox{equation in $C^\infty$} \xrightarrow{2^{nd} approx.} \mbox{equation in $\Bbb{R}^n$} \xrightarrow{1^{st} approx.} \mbox{numerical solution} $$
that is
$$ \mbox{functional equation} \to \mbox{matrix equation} \to \mbox{numerical analysis} $$

Considerations like floating point errors, numerical stability, and [well- and ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) go with the first type of approximation. Considerations like the operator in the original question go with the second. Let's focus on those.

In reducing a differential equation to a linear algebra problem, we may want to replace an infinite dimensional function space with a *finite dimensional subspace*. The goal is to choose a finite dimensional subspace where the problem becomes manageable with finite computing power, and then numerically solve it.

If we have a function space $\mathcal{V}$ and a finite dimensional subspace $V\subset\mathcal{V}$ which we believe is suitable for studying and approximating the problem, then the next step is to ask how we translate the functions from $\mathcal{V}$ to $\mathcal{V}$. The answer is: **via an operator like $T$ from the original question.** Once we have this operator, we want to study all sorts of things about it --- how it distorts distances (i.e. how good it is at approximating), what kind of functions are in its kernel or close to its kernel, what kinds of functions are badly approximated, how it interacts with the problem we want to solve, and so on.

To make this concrete, say we have a triangular mesh on a polygonal Euclidean domain and we want to study how well piecewise-polynomial interpolation on the mesh approximates smooth functions on the domain. We do this by studying triangle-by-triangle and examining how well piecewise-polynomial interpolation on a single triangle works for smooth functions. (One answer is given by the [*Bramble-Hilbert lemma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bramble%E2%80%93Hilbert_lemma); other answers in different norms are given by studying the remainder operator, $R = T-I$ in the notation of the question.) Once this is known, the error can be summed over triangles to produce estimates that make their way into the error estimates on various approximations of the solutions of linear partial differential equations on the domain.

I'm being very vague here, but I hope this provides some context and some justification for why questions like this are interesting to some people.

---

As an aside, the philosophy "*choose a good space!*" is also true in the the study of the solutions of differential equations. This is where spaces like the $L^p$ spaces, the Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}$ and $H^k$, the $BMO$ spaces, and so on come from: People found them useful contexts for studying various types of functional equations, identifying solutions, and studying the properties of the solutions.

Comment: Related remark: one can derive numerical methods for ODEs using formal power series. Namely, Taylor expansion *formally* tells us that $y(t+\Delta t)=e^{\Delta t D} y(t)$. This is of course not true in the usual sense, but it *is* true in the sense of asymptotic expansions, which means that we can derive a numerical method by writing out the power series and truncating it at finite order.